# How do you hide/show UISearchBar's scope bar with animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I want to show no scope bar when the table is empty (before the search bar edits for the first time), no scope bar when it's editing, and finally show it when editing done. I know about the UISearchBarDelegate protocol, but I don't know how to show/hide the scope bar with animation. I know UISearchBar has `setShowsScopeBar:`, but no `setShowsScopeBar:animated:` the way it does for `setShowsCancelButton:animated`.

**Edit**
It's important that to call `[searchBar sizeToFit]` after showing/hiding the scope bar. Is there a good way to animate this? (Should I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558475/how-do-you-animate-the-resizing-of-a-tableview-without-its-rows-subviews-getting)? It doesn't appear to work.)

Comment: Wondering the same thing, it's a little inconsistent.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's how to make the cancel button and the scope bar to be displayed only while editing.

Complete code with the small bonus of animating the cancel button’s (dis)appearance:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT - Version Swift 3**

```
public func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

    return true
}

public func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)

    return true
}
```

Source: http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=418

Comment: the code works, but it shows the scope bar on the same line as the search bar. Is there a way to dynamically display the scope bar, but bellow the search field?

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this, @andrei?

Answer (score 1):

**For the newer iOS versions (tested on 11-13), you don't have to implement any delegate methods for this to work.**

In iOS 13 the default behaviour is to always show the scope bar, even when search is not active. Previous iOS versions automatically show and hide the scope bar when search is active.

You need to add this in `viewDidLoad()`

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchController.automaticallyShowsScopeBar = true
}
```