# UISearchBar - scope bar animated

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, animated

I've found example of animated search-bar with scope bar under "UISearchDisplayDelegate Protocol Reference"([SearchBar-animated-sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848)
), here is a video preview:
[SearchBarAnimated-video](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2261256/searchBarAnimated.mov)

I've checked sample code, but I can't find the code that triggers animation.
Does anyone knows how to create that animation ? Do you have to use UISearchBarDelegate to get that animation ?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to control the animations of UISearchBar you have implement the delegates of UISearchDisplayController by extending  in your header file. The delegates are as follows;

```
    - (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
        CGRect headerViewFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
        headerViewFrame.origin.y -= 54.0f;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = headerViewFrame;

        CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
        tableViewFrame.origin.y -= 54.0f;
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    -(void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

        CGRect headerViewFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
        headerViewFrame.origin.y += 54.0f;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame = headerViewFrame;

        CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
        tableViewFrame.origin.y += 54.0f;
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: searchDisplayController is not deprecated in iOS8, replaced by searchController. Do you have any idea to deal with a searchBar with a compatibility between iOS7+

Comment: @popei Still on the look for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's built right in to `UISearchBar`. Apple does this for you, you don't have to call any method by yourself.

Basically, from the moment you set your search bar's `scopeButtonTitles` property, Apple will animate the scope bar.

Comment: Where do you have to add UISearchBar ? 
I've added it to tableView, but when I click on it, it doesn't move up to navigation title.
Do you have to call "searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;" to display scope bar(animated) ?

Comment: I think you're looking for my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302962/uisearchbar-sample-code/1304301#1304301

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question more useful though it doesn't automatically transition the search bar to the top of your view.

[How do you hide/show UISearchBar's scope bar with animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058015/how-do-you-hide-show-uisearchbars-scope-bar-with-animation)

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me in Xcode 6. If you have auto layout constraints in place then you may need to add in adjustments for them as I've done (didn't work without them).

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    searchBarHeightConstraint.constant = 88; // Changes from 44 to 88 with scope bar
    tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 480; // Changes from 524 to 480 with scope bar

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;
                         newFrame.origin.y = 88;
                         tableView.frame = newFrame;
                     }];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    searchBarHeightConstraint.constant = 44;
    tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 524;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect newFrame = tableView.frame;
                         newFrame.origin.y = 44;
                         tableView.frame = newFrame;
                     }];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### sizeToFit in an Animation block

The `UISearchBar` w/ scope bar is easily animated. UISearchBar has a height of 44.f before calling sizeToFit with the scope bar and then becomes 88.f. In my case, the `UISearchBar` was embedded in a `UITableView` within Interface Builder so it was not possible to add auto layout constraints.

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate methods

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        [searchBar sizeToFit];
    }];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```